# foreach xml node return selected element

Tags: php, html, xml, simplexml, domdocument

How can I get only selected value from my xml cdata tag?

So far with help in stackoverflow I can get all the `<b>` tags in a string

```
$result = simplexml_load_file($url, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

    foreach ($result->channel->item as $item) {
        $desc = $item->description;
        $dom = new DOMDocument($desc);
        $dom->loadHTML($desc);
        $bold_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('b');
        foreach($bold_tags as $b) {
            echo $b->nodeValue . "<br>";
        }
```

but it will echo out all data which are inside `<b>`, but I want to get only let's say price.
I red in stackoverflow  to use `->item(x)` to get that value, but nothing is working.If I put it like this `echo $b->nodeValue->item(2) . "<br>";` or `echo $b->item(2)->nodeValue . "<br>";`. So where should I put it or what should I use to get only `<b>` element with price. The price will always be in the same place.

Here is my CDATA from feed:

```
<a href="//www.ss.lv/msg/lv/real-estate/flats/riga/purvciems/deblb.html">
    <img align="right" border="0" src="//i.ss.lv/images/2014-10-01/349288/VHkAHkBlRlo=/1.t.jpg" width="160" height="120" alt="">
</a> District: <b><b>Purvciems</b></b><br />
Street: <b><b>Dudajeva g. 12</b></b><br />
Rooms: <b><b>2</b></b><br />
m2: <b><b>50</b></b><br />
Type: <b><b>LT proj.</b></b><br />
: <b><b>3</b> €</b><br />
Price: <b><b>150</b> €/mēn.</b><br />
<br />
<b><a href="//www.ss.lv/msg/lv/real-estate/flats/riga/purvciems/deblb.html">Apskatīt sludinājumu</a></b><br />
<br />
]]>
```

Comment: It's going to be pretty difficult to parse because it's so disorganised. Does [the API](https://www.ss.lv/lv/api/) offer any better options for getting data?

Comment: @ialarmedalien All their API gives me is some javascript code to add their sites window into my site or I can use RSS feed from this site with all information I need in this CDATA

Comment: @Santar hello santar check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method to parse those prices:

```
$url = "http://www.ss.lv/lv/real-estate/flats/riga/hand_over/rss/";
$result = simplexml_load_file($url, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$data = array();
foreach($result->channel->item as $item) {
    $temp = array();

    $title = (string) trim($item->title);
    $desc = $item->description;

    $temp['title'] = $title;

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $desc = mb_convert_encoding($desc, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
    $dom->loadHTML($desc);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
    $price_tag = $xpath->query('//text()[contains(., "Cena")]'); // target Cena,
    // i didn't know this was PRICE in translation haha
    $price = $price_tag->item(0)->nextSibling->nodeValue;
    $temp['price'] = $price;
    $data[] = $temp ;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Okay, for the explanation:

So the goal is getting those prices which resides in the `<description>` tag inside the CDATA.

So each `<item>` node contains them which looks like this:

```
<a href="//www.ss.lv/msg/lv/real-estate/flats/riga/centre/colfo.html">
    <img align=right border=0 src="//i.ss.lv/images/2014-08-25/346391/VHkPH0FiQVo=/1.t.jpg" width="160" height="120" alt="">
</a>
Rajons: <b>centrs</b>
<br/>Iela: <b>Rūpniecības 7</b><br/>Ist.: <b>4</b>
<br/>m2: <b>145</b><br/>Sērija: <b>Renov.</b><br/>: <b>10.34 €</b>
<br/>Cena: <b>1,500 €/mēn.</b><br/>
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ // this one
<br/><b><a href="//www.ss.lv/msg/lv/real-estate/flats/riga/centre/colfo.html">Apskatīt sludinājumu</a></b><br/><br/>
```

So the goal is, by using xpath, search for the Prices (Cena). So according to markup this a normal text node (Not an element or is not a tag).

So we target that text element which contains "Cena":

```
//text()[contains(., "Cena")]
```

So each Cena/Price it has the next sibling `<b>` tags which contain that particular value, so we target each Cena/Price and point the next sibling which is `<b>` tag

```
item(0)->nextSibling->nodeValue
Cena/Price -> nextSibling (which is b tag) -> its value
```

Comment: Thanks. With your solution I am able to get all values I need,
but can you explain little bit your code, so I know what it does not simply copy paste it. Like why we used xpath but in previous question DOM parsing?

Comment: hello @Santar i've added the explanation